# undefined method `assertions' in routing spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, rspec-rails

`` 1) JunksController routing routes to #index
     Failure/Error: get("/junks").should route_to("junks#index")
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `assertions' for #<#<Class:0x007ff8d62c8568>:0x007ff8d13e2f20>
     # ./spec/routing/junks_routing_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>' ``

The only hint I have is that MiniTest v5 is throwing deprecation warnings.

`` MiniTest::Unit::TestCase is now Minitest::Test. From /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit/testcase.rb:8:in `<module:Unit>' ``

In a recent update of Gems, I started getting an undefined method `assertions' for all of my routing specs. I generated a new scaffold, it too is raising the same error

Versions:

- rails (3.2.13)
- rspec (2.13.0)
- rspec-core (~> 2.13.0)
- rspec-expectations (~> 2.13.0)
- rspec-mocks (~> 2.13.0)
- rspec-rails (2.13.2)
- minitest (5.0.2)
- capybara (2.1.0)
- rack-test (0.6.2)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out the Minitest gem was the culprit. I locked the gem's version and all routing specs are passing again. Yea!

`gem 'minitest', '~> 4.0'`