# Rails 4 and RSpec, undefined method `assertions' in routing spec

Tags: rspec2, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, minitest

I'm having what appears to be the same issue as [undefined method `assertions' in routing spec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16735036/undefined-method-assertions-in-routing-spec) but I'm running Rails 4 and it is locked to minitest 5.0 or greater. Thus the solution to use minitest 4.7 I can't make work. Is there a work around for this? Where would I report the bug?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This problem is caused by a change in minitest 5.0 documented here:

# https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/issues/286

is fixed by using:

```
gem "rspec-rails", '~> 2.14.0.rc1'
```

in the gemfile.